# How to execute mysql statement from command line

Tags: mysql

I need to run the below command from the command line.  How do I do that on ubuntu?  It works in the shell but need to execute for a chef recepie.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following

> echo "grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by
>   'password';" | mysql -u root -p

HTH